# Online design tool (Like Web2Print) with Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, frameworks

I'm looking to create an editor or design tool that allows me to create and save designs made from multiple uploaded images, custom controls, etc. Maybe using HTML5 canvas and JavaScript. Is there any good Angular 2 component for doing something like this?

Thank you for your help

Arturo M.